# I have 5 specs (test1.js, test2.js,..), I want to execute the test specs one by one in protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor

Like if test1.js is finished than automatically test2.js will start and so on.

Comment: Please add some more details of your setup and your research efforts so far and where you are stuck.

Comment: @OvidiuDolha: This is my conf file: exports.config = {
  directConnect: true,
        framework: 'jasmine'
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
  defaultTimeoutInterval: 640000
 },suites: { samples: ['test0', 'test1', 'test2', 'test3'] }, capabilities: {
   browserName: 'chrome',
   shardTestFiles: true,

Answer (score 0):

In Protractor Js configuration File there is a object name `suites` in which you define your test specs, for execution you can place your files here in the order you want

```
suites: {
        login: 'login/test1.spec.js', 
        dashboard: 'dashboard/test2.spec.js',
    },
```

Comment: its not working for me. test1 spec is shown and then the window is closed. Right after that, test2 is shown and the window is closed.

Comment: which browser you r using

Comment: Browser: chrome

Comment: it should work than, please post you config file in que so we can look that.

Comment: exports.config = {
  directConnect: true,
        framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
  defaultTimeoutInterval: 640000000
 }, 
 suites: {
        login: 'login/01-login.js', 
        dashboard: 'dashboard/02-dashboard.js', 
  Accounts: 'Accounts/03-Accounts.js'
    },  
  capabilities: {
   browserName: 'chrome',
   shardTestFiles: true,
          maxInstances: 1,
   
  },

Comment: chage capabilities object as  capabilities: {
  'browserName': 'chrome',
  chromeOptions: {
   args: ['--no-sandbox'],
  },
  "platform": "ANY",
  "version": ""
 },